# Choosing Youtube API v3 vs v2 for Python GUI application

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am looking into writing a Python GUI app to make use of the Youtube API. This app intends to gather meta data and visualize the results in a variety of methods, however, I am unsure as to which API to use. V2 has plenty of documentation online and uses XML, while V3 is still experimental and uses JSON. Will the code examples for V2 be portable to V3 ?

Link: [Python - v2 documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube v3 is not marked as experimental. The code samples can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python).

Your link points to the 1.0 documentation. 1.0 has been deprecated.